# Delay a default event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to delay a page change in react so that i can add a fade out animation so i need to delay the click event before the page actually changes. Im currently using React.

Here is my code so far.

```
export default function Modal({setTopOf}) {
  const {globalState:{isOpen}, dispatch} = useContext(GlobalContext)
  return (
    <Contain>
      <Outer isOpen={isOpen} onClick={()=>{
         dispatch({type:'setOpen',value:false})
        
      }}></Outer>
      <Inner isOpen={isOpen}>
        {
          nav.map(nav => <Link href={nav.link}><P onClick={(e)=>{
          
            e.preventDefault()


          }}><a>{nav.name}</a></P></Link>)
        }
      </Inner>
    </Contain>
  )
}
```

The prevent default will stop the page change and then i want to send the event after a 0.2 second delay, any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `setTimeout`? But a better way is delaying within the `setOpen` action instead on the event

Comment: That setOpen doesnt have anything to do with the question sorry, I removed it. I plan on using set time out but dont know how to reinitiate the event after i prevented it

Answer (score 1):

```
export default function Modal({setTopOf}) {
    const {globalState:{isOpen}, dispatch} = useContext(GlobalContext)
    const [firstClick, setFirstClick] = useState(false)

    const delayedPageChange = (e) => {
        
        if(!firstClick) {
            e.preventDefault()
            setFirstClick(true)
            setTimeout(() => {
                e.currentTarget.click()
            },200)
        } else {
            setFirstClick(false)
        }
    }
    return (
      <Contain>
        <Outer 
            isOpen={isOpen}
            onClick={()=>{ dispatch({type:'setOpen',value:false})}}
        />     
        <Inner isOpen={isOpen}>
          {
            nav.map(nav => (
                <Link href={nav.link}>
                    <P onClick={delayedPageChange}>
                        <a>{nav.name}</a>
                    </P>
                </Link>
                )
            )
          }
        </Inner>
      </Contain>
    )
  }
```

Try this with setTimeout end event re-trigger management.

Comment: Hi, Thanks - Found this really cool and i will definitely use this when im using vanilla js. It doesnt seem to work with react because react has Synthetic events and doesnt allow for  currentTarget to be used in this scenario. I instead used next router. This is a really slick idea though thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this which seems to work

```
import React from 'react'
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'

export default function CustomLink(props) {
  const path = props.path
  const delay = props.delay || 2000
  
  // get the delay from a theme somehow

  

  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <span onClick={()=>{
      setTimeout(()=>{
        router.push(path)
      },delay)
    }}>
      {props.children}
    </span>
  )
}
```